# Changing div styles using a javascript timer with different intervals

Tags: php, javascript, timer, styles

Currently I have the following code creating my timer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var interval;
var minutes = 8;
var seconds = 10;

function countdown(element) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        var el = document.getElementById(element);
        if(seconds == 0) {
            if(minutes == 0) {
                alert(el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!");                    
                clearInterval(interval);
                return;
            } else {
                minutes--;
                seconds = 60;
            }
        }
        if(minutes > 0) {
            var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
        } else {
            var minute_text = '';
        }
        var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
        el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
        seconds--;
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

And I use the following buttons to trigger it:

```
<input type="button" onclick="countdown('countdown');" value="Start" />
<input type="button" onclick="clearInterval(interval);" value="Pause" />
```

How can I track the timer and change page styles as time goes by?

For example, when I click start I want to highlight one div, after 5 seconds I want to highlight another div and unhighlight the first, 20 seconds after that I want to change the highlight again, 10 seconds after that I change the highlight again, and so on.

The intervals should be able to be different times, but most cases will follow the pattern above (0, 5, 5, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10...) so that's a good starting place. The total length of the timer is always 8 minutes, so the intervals can be hard coded and I could use PHP to select the correct code (although inefficient, probably easiest).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post examples of what you currently have?

Comment: you can create a callback function inside of countdown() then check the time and highlight div's accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in a switch statement on the elapsed time.

For each specified interval, set the div in question, and unset the others.

```
//at the beginning of the script
var origtime = minutes*60+seconds;

//...snip to countdown function

var timeleft = minutes*60+seconds;
switch(origtime - timeleft)
{
case 0: highlightfirstdiv(); break;
case 5: highlightseconddiv(); break;
case 10: highlightthirddiv(); break;
...
case x: highlightfinaldiv(); break;
}
```

Comment: I tried putting this into the code above, but I can't get it to work. I have this:

`var origtime = minutes*60+seconds;
function countdown(element) {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
  var timeleft = minutes*60+seconds;
  switch(origtime - timeleft)
  {
  case 0: div1(); break;
  case 5: div2(); break;
        }
...`


and

`function div1() {
document.getElementById("div1").style.property="background:#00FF00;"
 }
 function div2() {  document.getElementById("div1").style.property="background:#fff;"
document.getElementById("div2").style.property="background:#00FF00;"
 }`

Comment: Ahhhh, genius me was setting `origtime = minutes*60+seconds;` before setting minutes and seconds. Thank you!